# Can't Access Instance Variable Inside Method of same Class?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I am having difficulty accessing the variable 'InvalidAlready' Inside of the method .isLatinSquare() and I have no idea why:/

Part of Code:

```
public class LatinSquare {
    private boolean invalidAlready = false;

    //Setter and Getters for invalidAlready
    public void setInvalid(){
        invalidAlready = true;
    }

    public boolean testInvalid(){
        return invalidAlready;
    }

    //Testing method to show whether LatinSquare is valid
    public boolean isLatinSquare(int[][] array) {
         if (square.getInvalid() = true) {
             return false;
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Main Code Here
        LatinSquare square= new LatinSquare();
```

The main problem I am having is with the if statement inside the isLatinSquare() method. At the if statement there is an error that says:Cannot invoke testInvalid() on the primitive type boolean

In the main method I am able to use this perfectly fine for my if statements in order to test whether the InvalidAlready object is true or false.

Sorry I am somewhat new to java :/ Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: but `InvalidAlready` is a `boolean`, so it has no methods.

Comment: There are naming problems. I've made some edits, awaiting review

Comment: But in the main method I created an object called 'InvalidAlready'

Comment: You had two variables called InvalidAlready. It causes confusion. Also, Java convention is object names have a leading capital, instances / variables lead with a lower case letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InvalidAlready` is a primitive `boolean` type, so there is no `getInvalid()` method defined on it:

```
public boolean isLatinSquare(int[][] array){

     if (InvalidAlready.getInvalid() = true) // this is wrong
     {
     ...         
     }
}
```

You could do something like this instead:

```
public boolean isLatinSquare(int[][] array){

     if (InvalidAlready)
     {
        // do stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked :) I don't know how I could be so dumb lol. I think I confused myself by making an object called InvalidAlready. By using that object I was able to manipulate the instance variable and determine whether something was invalid already by calling it with the get method. I didn't show much of my main code but I suppose it would help show what I was doing.

Comment: No worries. If you feel the answer is acceptable please click the green check mark next to it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
if (invalidAlready){
    return false;
}
```

InvalidAlready is a boolean primitive, it has not method, and can be true or false;

Answer (score 0):

Your LatinSquare class doesn't have a getInvalid() method...
You should use the method named testInvalid(), or rename it to correspond to getInvalid()